# Boiler plan for maintenance and repairs

Tags: insurance

I have a boiler protection plan covering repairs and annual service. I have been with the company for over 5years and though they have renewed my cover and take the monthly premium they failed to inform me that they had changed their conditions and they do not now cover rented properties. The company had been fully aware that the plan was for a rented property and had been servicing and repairing the boiler when needed for the past 4years. They have renewed the policy even though they had changed their policy conditions not to cover rental properties and continued to take the monthly premium. Is this fraud to take money for a service you cannot provide and what action can I take

Comment: You might want to consult law.stackexchange instead.  However, if this is for a smallish amount of money you may check out small claims court.  Typically the amount is limited to 2500 to 5000.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a tag with the location - from the terminology I suspect the UK?

Comment: "The company had been fully aware that the plan was for a rented property" - in what way was the company fully aware?  In other words, how do you go about proving this part of your question?